# Vue JS 2 Way Binding Implementation

Tags: vue.js

I'm not sure where or how to ask this question.

I'm trying to understand how Vue JS 2 way binding is implemented. Just to be clear, not how to use 2 way binding.

I've tried to dig in the source code on their github https://github.com/vuejs/vue , but I'm having hard time navigating through it.

Is there anybody who's more familiar with their code-base that can point me to the section where I should be looking?

Comment: As far as I know VueJs uses Object.defineProperty and its getter and setter to react to changes that are made to a certain prop.

Comment: Also see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html